# Vue, Mocha and webpack chunks configuration?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, webpack, optimization, mocha.js

I have a Vue2 application:

The vue.config file have a webpack bundle optimization to split the app into chunks to reduce file size:

```
module.exports = {
  ...,
  configureWebpack: {
    optimization: {
      runtimeChunk: "single",
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: "all"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I'm trying to integrate mocha to enable testing, but I can see that it recognise the tests only when I remove the above optimization.

With optimization:
[image]

Without optimization:
[image]

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: any update on the mater ? I am facing the same issue